# Is there a exporter for rabbitmq:v3.5.6

Tags: rabbitmq, exporter

I want monitor the rabbitmq:v3.5.6 by prometheus, so,the firstly I need a exporter to scrape the rabbitmq's Metrics. I  checked the official website and
don't find there is any exporter can corresponde to rabbitmq3.5.6 version. someone can advise me ?

Comment: Second hit in a simple search for 'rabbitmq metrics': https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html

Comment: BTW, [RabbitMQ 3.5.x reached its EOL at 31 October 2016](https://www.rabbitmq.com/versions.html). You should upgrade to 3.7 *now*.